400 Bad Request when handling file inputs within Flask, JS, and HTML Script
I am creating a Flask Python Application that will use JS along with HTML, to create a form that allows the user to input a file. During my testing I am receiving a 400 Bad Request within the 'POST' of submit.
so, the relevant code is as follows:
HTML
<label for="inputYaml">Select your .yaml file:</label>
<input type="file" id="inputYaml" name="inputYaml" accept=".yaml">

JS
var userInputYamlForm = document.getElementById('userInputYaml');

userInputYamlForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var formData = new FormData(this);
   sendDataToFlask('/submit', formData);
});

function sendDataToFlask(url, data) {
   fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
   }).then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
         throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
      return response.json();
   }).then(data => {
      showPopup();
   }).catch(error => {
      ('There was an error!', error);
   });
}

The function showPopup() is just a popup window that shows up when the user submits the form, then resets the form
Python
def save_file(file, path):
   try:
      os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path), exist_ok=True)
      file.save(path)
   except Exception as e:
      raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to save file {file.filename}: {str(e)}")

@app.route('/submit'. method=['POST'])
def submit_files():
   files = request.files
   try:
      yaml_file = files['inputYaml']
      if yaml_file and yaml_file.filename.endswith('yaml'):
         save_file(yaml_file, '/path/to/where/it/needs/to/be/saved')
      else:
         return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid YAML files'}), 400
      # handling of other files if required
   except Exception as e:
      return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

I am unsure of where I am going wrong, but because it is a 400 BAD REQUEST, I presume it is within the file being invalid, even during the base test case which is a .yaml file.

Have you verified that userInputYamlForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) even fires?

Please post complete FORM as used in your HTML

@roganjosh I have put test messages in there that are being pushed to the console. I also have verified that sendDataToFlask is also being started as my test console.log output is sending.

@Daweo I am unable to do so, but it is a bunch of select statements, that when option1 is selected, then the user needs to input a file, when option2 is selected, then the user does not need to input a file

@Ed-Ryan then I might only guess that you prompty ignored requirement for setting enctype to multipart/form-data which is required for file upload

Append files to formData like this
   // Get the file input element and its files
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('inputYaml');
    const files = fileInput.files; // This is a FileList object

    // Create a new FormData object
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Loop through each file and append it to the FormData object
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        formData.append('files[]', files[i], files[i].name);
    }
    // Log the FormData entries for debugging purposes (optional)
    for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0], pair[1]);
    }

For backend
files = request.files.getlist('files')

